# Splitting the integers 1 to 36

Tags: mathematics, optimization, number-theory, graph-theory

Split the integers 1 to 36 into two sets, *A* and *B*, such that any number in set *A* has a common divisor greater than 1 with no more than two other numbers in *A*, but for every number in *B* there are at least three numbers in *A* with which it has a common divisor.

How large can set *A* be?

In general, for which *N* is such a splitting of the integers 1 to *N* possible?

Comment: This talk by Peter Wrinkler at Gathering for Gardner is the origin of this problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RQtCRpWvVuw&t=397s

Comment: Can *B* be empty?

Answer (score 7):

Via integer linear programming, the largest $|A|$ is

> $17$, attained by $A=\{1,2,3,5,7,9,11,13,16,17,19,23,25,27,29,31,32\}$

and the smallest $|A|$ is

> $14$, attained by $A=\{1,5,7,11,12,13,17,18,19,23,25,29,31,36\}$.

Answer (score 2):

If *B* can be empty, using this strategy would get us this partition

> $A$ includes 1, all prime numbers <= $N$ and largest 2 exponents for each prime <= $N$

Examples

> $ N = 1, A = \{1\}$ 
>  $ N = 2, A = \{1, 2\}$ 
>  $ N = 3, A = \{1, 2, 3\}$ 
>  $ N = 4, A = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ 
>  $ N = 5, A = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ 
>  $ N = 6, A = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ 
>  $ N = 7, A = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7\}$ 
>  $ N = 8, A = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8\}$ 
>  $ N = 9, A = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9\}$ 
>  $ N = 10, A = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9\}$ 
>  $ N = 11, A = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11\}$ 
>  $ N = 12, A = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11\}$ 
>  $ N = 13, A = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13\}$ 
>  $ N = 14, A = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13\}$ 
>  $ N = 15, A = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13\}$ 
>  $ N = 16, A = \{1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 16\}$ 
>  $ N = 17, A = \{1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 16, 17\}$ 
>  $ N = 18, A = \{1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 16, 17\}$ 
>  $ N = 19, A = \{1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 16, 17, 19\}$ 
>  $ N = 20, A = \{1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 16, 17, 19\}$ 
>  $ N = 21, A = \{1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 16, 17, 19\}$ 
>  $ N = 22, A = \{1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 16, 17, 19\}$ 
>  $ N = 23, A = \{1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 16, 17, 19, 23\}$ 
>  $ N = 24, A = \{1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 16, 17, 19, 23\}$ 
>  $ N = 25, A = \{1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 16, 17, 19, 23, 25\}$ 
>  $ N = 26, A = \{1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 16, 17, 19, 23, 25\}$ 
>  $ N = 27, A = \{1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 16, 17, 19, 23, 25, 27\}$ 
>  $ N = 28, A = \{1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 16, 17, 19, 23, 25, 27\}$ 
>  $ N = 29, A = \{1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 16, 17, 19, 23, 25, 27, 29\}$ 
>  $ N = 30, A = \{1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 16, 17, 19, 23, 25, 27, 29\}$ 
>  $ N = 31, A = \{1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 16, 17, 19, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31\}$ 
>  $ N = 32, A = \{1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 16, 17, 19, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 32\}$ 
>  $ N = 33, A = \{1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 16, 17, 19, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 32\}$ 
>  $ N = 34, A = \{1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 16, 17, 19, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 32\}$ 
>  $ N = 35, A = \{1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 16, 17, 19, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 32\}$ 
>  $ N = 36, A = \{1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 16, 17, 19, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 32\}$ 
>  $ N = 37, A = \{1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 16, 17, 19, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 32, 37\}$ 
>  $ N = 38, A = \{1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 16, 17, 19, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 32, 37\}$ 
>  $ N = 39, A = \{1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 16, 17, 19, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 32, 37\}$

I verified this with a [program](https://gist.github.com/sudhackar/32e61ae4add3c2ce68af14f7095377fd#file-115935-c) for about 10**5 and it looked satisfiable.